# Submit a form from another form, $_POST values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value coming from another form in the same page called $_POST['serial']. And i want to use this value to run a query in another form but after I submit the second form nothing happened and the query not running.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['serial'])) {
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Click to use</button>
    </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET status = 'inactive' WHERE serial = '$serial'");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Make the first variable a hidden input value in your second form.

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass the variable along you would create a hidden input on your second form to contain the value:

```
<?php
    // check and clean up the passed variable 
    $serial = isset($_POST['serial']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['serial']) : '';
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="serial" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>" />        
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Click to use</button>
</form>
```

---

**For Safety's Sake**

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

**Additional Thoughts**

If you're planning to do a two-step form you'll likely want to place all of the data processing *outside* of the form page, in a separate PHP file. With the limited code that you have shown I fear that we will miss something in our answers which will lead you to additional questions because your code still isn't working as you would expect.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @JayBlanchard — Yes, but the XSS problem is a new one that you introduced (and which your SQL injection focused edit does not address)

Comment: @JayBlanchard — `value="<?php echo $serial; ?>"` creates the XSS problem. Prepared statements won't help with it.

Comment: Thanks for your advise using another way of mysql statements, and thanks again for your solution, it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

A button needs a name **and** a value to be successful. Your button doesn't have a value so `$_POST['submit']` will be undefined.

Add a `value` attribute to your `<button>` element.

---

After you do that, `$serial` will be undefined because your form doesn't submit that.

You need to include it in your form too:

```
<input type="hidden" name="serial" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($serial); ?>">
```

Comment: Sidenote: since the OP is using it in the same file, `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($serial); ?>"` will throw an undefined variable serial notice in HTML source on initial page load.